Calcular Columna RangoBaseDinamico en DataFrame
Tengo un archivo Excel con datos de rangos mensuales que se alcanzan por diferentes cuentas. Necesito calcular una columna adicional llamada RangoBaseDinamico basado en las siguientes reglas:

El RangoBaseFijo es el rango inicial de cada cuenta.
El RangoBaseDinamico debe actualizarse a un nuevo rango si un rango superior al RangoBaseDinamico actual es alcanzado tres veces.
Los rangos inferiores al RangoBaseDinamico actual no deben contar para actualizar el rango base dinámico.

Ejemplo:
Supongamos que tengo los siguientes datos de ejemplo:



Periodo
AccountNumber
RangoMes
RangoBaseFijo




2024-01
70956201
3
1


2024-02
70956201
3.5
1


2024-03
70956201
3.5
1


2024-04
70956201
3.5
1


2024-05
70956201
3
1


2024-06
70956201
2
1


2024-07
70956201
9
1



El resultado esperado para RangoBaseDinamico sería:



Periodo
AccountNumber
RangoMes
RangoBaseFijo
RangoBaseDinamico




2024-01
70956201
3
1
1


2024-02
70956201
3.5
1
1


2024-03
70956201
3.5
1
3


2024-04
70956201
3.5
1
3.5


2024-05
70956201
3
1
3.5


2024-06
70956201
2
1
3.5


2024-07
70956201
9
1
3.5


2024-08
70956201
3.5
1
3.5


2024-09
70956201
9
1
3.5


2024-10
70956201
2
1
3.5


2024-11
70956201
9
1
9.0



Reglas:

En el periodo de 2024-03, el RangoBaseDinamico se actualiza a 3 porque el rango 3 fue alcanzado tres veces (enero, febrero, marzo).
En el periodo de 2024-04, el RangoBaseDinamico se actualiza a 3.5 porque el rango 3.5 fue alcanzado tres veces (febrero, marzo, abril).
Los rangos menores que 3.5 después de abril no afectan el RangoBaseDinamico.

Datos y Código Actual:
Adjunto el archivo DATOS A CALCULAR.xlsx y el código que he intentado hasta ahora. Necesito ayuda para ajustar la lógica y obtener el resultado correcto.
import pandas as pd

# Cargar el archivo de datos
file_path = 'C:\\Users\\jonathanm\\Downloads\\DATOS A CALCULAR.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(file_path)

# Convertir la columna 'Periodo' a formato datetime
data['Periodo'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Periodo'], format='%Y-%m')

# Ordenar los datos por AccountNumber y Periodo
data.sort_values(by=['AccountNumber', 'Periodo'], inplace=True)

# Agregar la columna de Rango Base Fijo
data['RangoBaseFijo'] = data['RangoBase']

# Inicializar la columna de Rango Base Dinámico con tipo de dato float
data['RangoBaseDinamico'] = data['RangoBase'].astype(float)

# Diccionario para almacenar el conteo de rangos por AccountNumber
consecutive_counts = {}

# Iterar a través de las filas para calcular el Rango Base Dinámico
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    account_number = row['AccountNumber']
    rango_mes = row['RangoMes']
    
    if account_number not in consecutive_counts:
        consecutive_counts[account_number] = {'counts': {}, 'last_dynamic_rango': row['RangoBase']}
    
    last_dynamic_rango = consecutive_counts[account_number]['last_dynamic_rango']
    
    if rango_mes > last_dynamic_rango:
        if rango_mes in consecutive_counts[account_number]['counts']:
            consecutive_counts[account_number]['counts'][rango_mes] += 1
        else:
            consecutive_counts[account_number][rango_mes] = 1
        
        if consecutive_counts[account_number]['counts'][rango_mes] >= 3:
            consecutive_counts[account_number]['last_dynamic_rango'] = rango_mes
    
    data.loc[index, 'RangoBaseDinamico'] = consecutive_counts[account_number]['last_dynamic_rango']

# Mostrar las primeras 10 filas del DataFrame resultante, incluyendo RangoBaseFijo
print(data[['AccountNumber', 'Periodo', 'RangoMes', 'RangoBaseFijo', 'RangoBaseDinamico']].head(10))

Este codigo me da como resultado :



Periodo
AccountNumber
RangoMes
RangoBaseFijo
RangoBaseDinamico




2024-01
70956201
3
1
1


2024-02
70956201
3.5
1
1


2024-03
70956201
3.5
1
1


2024-04
70956201
3.5
1
3.5



Cosa que no es lo esperado.
Necesito:

Revisar y corregir el código para asegurar que RangoBaseDinamico se actualice correctamente basado en las reglas mencionadas.
Asegurar que los rangos que no superan el RangoBaseDinamico actual no afecten la actualización.

Gracias por tu ayuda.
